# Bundle Product (Bundle Items option is missing in Admin )

Tags: bundle, bundle-product

I been using Magento 2.1.9 i usually use simple product mostly. today I wanted to bundle a product - I just noticed that Bundle Items option is missing from the list. so I logged into a generic Magento 2 demo store and I see when I select Bundle Product (bundle Items Tab is there). can some one please help get that to work please on my store

here is what I see when I choose Bundle Product in my magento 2.1.9

[image: Bundle Products]

Comment: Are you editing an existing product or creating a new product?

Comment: Creating a new product.

Comment: I'm in 2.2 branch and the Add Product button has a down arrow that when clicked allows the selection of the type of product to be created.

Comment: Yes, correct I have the same - when I select bundle product, like i said Bundle items tab is missing